Logical Error in my implementation for the problem "Draughts" of Codechef
I have written this code for the problem "Draughts" of codechef but only few testcases are getting passed. Can anyone tell what is the error in my logic?
Furik and Rubik have come to the sanatorium, which consists of N rooms and M passageways. Each passageway connects two rooms, and there is at most one way to move between each pair of rooms. Some rooms have opened windows. There is a draught between two different rooms if both rooms have opened windows, and are connected with each other by some way.
Furik is interested in one question: what is the number of pairs of rooms, which have a draught between them. Rubik wants to know what is the number of the rooms, which have at least one draught passing through the room.
Input:
The first line contains two space-separated integers N and M. The next line contains N integers, where the ith number is equal to 1, if the window in the room number i is opened, otherwise 0. Then the next M lines contain pairs of integers, where the ith pair denotes the numbers of the connected rooms by ith passageway. Consider that the rooms are numerated by different integers from 1 to N.
Below is my implementation for the problem:
class DisjointSet {
public: 
    vector<int> dsize, parent, closed;
    DisjointSet(int n) {
        dsize.resize(n+1, 1);
        closed.resize(n+1);
        parent.resize(n+1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) parent[i] = i;
    }

    int findParent(int u) {
        if (parent[u] == u) return u;
       return parent[u] = findParent(parent[u]);
    }

    void unionBySize(int u, int v) {
        int pu = findParent(u), pv = findParent(v);
        if (pu == pv) return;
    
        if (dsize[pu] < dsize[pv]) {
            parent[pu] = pv;
            dsize[pv] += dsize[pu];
            closed[pv] += closed[pu];
        } else {
            parent[pv] = pu;
            dsize[pu] += dsize[pv];
            closed[pu] += closed[pv];
        }
    }
};

pair<int, int> solve(int n, DisjointSet &dset, vector<int> &windows) {
    int pairs = 0, rooms = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (dset.findParent(i) == i) {
            int openWindows = dset.dsize[i] - dset.closed[i];
            if (openWindows > 1) {
                rooms += openWindows;
                pairs += (openWindows * (openWindows - 1)) / 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return {pairs, rooms};
}

int main() {
    int N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    DisjointSet dset(N);
    vector<int> windows(N+1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        cin >> windows[i];
        if (windows[i] == 0) dset.closed[i]++;
    }
    while (M--) {
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        dset.unionBySize(v, u);
    }
    pair<int, int> ans = solve(N, dset, windows);
    cout << ans.first << " " << ans.second << endl;
    return 0;
}


Can you share any test cases that it fails?

Thank you for responding, Sorry, but the test cases where my code fails is hidden.

Then maybe you could explain your "logic"?

Each room starts as its own set. Rooms connected by passageways are merged using the unionBySize function. The closed array tracks rooms with closed windows. If a room has a closed window (windows[i] == 0), its closed[i] count is incremented. After merging, the number of rooms with open windows for a set is given by: (dsize[i] - closed[i]). If more than one room has open windows, draughts between pairs of rooms are counted using the formula openWindows * (openWindows - 1) / 2. Also, count how many rooms are part of at least one draught.
This is the overall logic.
